# C# / WPF Bitmap remains white after setting some values (with LockBits)

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, bitmap

Using MS Visual Studio 2013, having this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace SplashNS
{    

    public partial class DocumentWindow : Window
    {
        public SplashFile File;

        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

        private BitmapSource _loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
        {
            IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
            BitmapSource bs = null;
            try
            {
                bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
                   IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(ip);
            }

            return bs;
        }

        public DocumentWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Bitmap canvas = new Bitmap(663, 356);
            BitmapData bmd = canvas.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, canvas.PixelFormat);
            int PixelSize = 4;

            unsafe
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < canvas.Height; y++)
                {
                    byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < canvas.Width; x++)
                    {
                        row[x * PixelSize] = 255;    
                    }
                }
            }
            canvas.UnlockBits(bmd);          
            SplashCanvas.Source = this._loadBitmap(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't work. It generates a white bitmap instead of one with all blue pixels. No errors are displayed.

I guess, it must be a noob issue, but I am a beginner. I suppose it must be something with the pixel format, but I can also be wrong with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be creating an old-style `System.Drawing.Bitmap` then converting it to WPF, however WPF has a pretty complete set of utilities for creating bitmaps from scratch using [`WritableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See this article for an overview: [Foundations: Bitmaps and Pixel Bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534995.aspx).

For instance, here's code that creates a solid bitmap of a given size and color:

```
public static class BitmapHelper
{
    public unsafe static BitmapSource CreateSolidBitmap(int width, int height, double dpiX, double dpiY, Color color)
    {
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
        var format = bitmap.Format;
        int blueIndex, greenIndex, redIndex, alphaIndex;
        int bitsPerPixel, bytesPerPixel;
        if (!TryParsePixelFormat(format, out bitsPerPixel, out bytesPerPixel, out blueIndex, out greenIndex, out redIndex, out alphaIndex))
            return null;
        var byteWidth = bytesPerPixel * width;
        bitmap.Lock();
        try
        {
            var backBuffer = (byte*)bitmap.BackBuffer.ToPointer();
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < height; iRow++)
            {
                var row = backBuffer + (iRow * bitmap.BackBufferStride);
                for (byte* pixel = row, endRow = row + byteWidth; pixel < endRow; pixel += bytesPerPixel)
                {
                    pixel[blueIndex] = color.B;
                    pixel[greenIndex] = color.G;
                    pixel[redIndex] = color.R;
                    if (alphaIndex >= 0)
                        pixel[alphaIndex] = color.A;
                }
            }
            bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height));
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.Unlock();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    static int BlueIndex = 0;
    static int GreenIndex = 1;
    static int RedIndex = 2;
    static int AlphaIndex = 3;

    private static bool TryFindColorIndex(PixelFormatChannelMask mask, out int index)
    {
        var maskList = mask.Mask;
        for (int i = 0, count = maskList.Count; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (maskList[i] == 255)
            {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
        index = -1;
        return false;
    }

    static bool TryParsePixelFormat(PixelFormat format, out int bitsPerPixel, out int bytesPerPixel, out int blueIndex, out int greenIndex, out int redIndex, out int alphaIndex)
    {
        // Currently only implemented for non-indexed formats with 3 or 4 bytes
        // per color.
        bitsPerPixel = format.BitsPerPixel;
        if ((bitsPerPixel % 8) != 0)
        {
            bytesPerPixel = blueIndex = greenIndex = redIndex = alphaIndex = -1;
            return false;
        }

        bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;

        var masks = format.Masks;
        int maskCount = masks.Count;

        if (maskCount == 3 || maskCount == 4)
        {
            var blueMask = masks[BlueIndex];
            var greenMask = masks[GreenIndex];
            var redMask = masks[RedIndex];

            if (!TryFindColorIndex(blueMask, out blueIndex)
                || !TryFindColorIndex(greenMask, out greenIndex)
                || !TryFindColorIndex(redMask, out redIndex))
            {
                bytesPerPixel = blueIndex = greenIndex = redIndex = alphaIndex = -1;
                return false;
            }

            if (maskCount == 3)
            {
                alphaIndex = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!TryFindColorIndex(masks[AlphaIndex], out alphaIndex))
                    alphaIndex = -1;
            }

            return true;
        }

        bytesPerPixel = blueIndex = greenIndex = redIndex = alphaIndex = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since this is a static method it doesn't know the DPI for your running application, however you can get it inside your main window (or any other window) like this:

```
    PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);

    double dpiX = 96.0, dpiY = 96.0;
    if (source != null)
    {
        dpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
        dpiY = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
    }
```

96 seems to get used by convention when this is not available.

Comment: @Clemens - thanks.  I adapted this answer from some code I wrote to apply transforms to writable bitmaps.  The code example shown by Microsoft creates an indexed bitmap, which will be smaller (good) but trickier to modify further (maybe bad).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you specify `ImageLockMode.ReadOnly` in the `flags` parameter of you `LockBits` call.

Try using `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite` (or `ImageLockMode.WriteOnly`) instead.